# widget_text widget doesn't work with shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, text, filter, widget, shortcode

Hi all I am having a big issue with the shortcodes not working in text_widget. I have added the appropriate codes

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

I am still unsuccessful, is there any troubleshoot techniques I can used or be advised to solve this issue myself?

Also the shortcodes work perfectly in the_content and the_excerpt.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode');  
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add a priority .

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode', 11);
```

if not successful - try to disable all plugins and change theme to default - there is a slight , albeit statistically existing possibility that one of the plugins is removing this filter for some obscure reason...

Comment: did you try the priority ? and disabled themes as well ??

Comment: yes I did both and still no luck. anything could be conflicting with it?

Comment: if you disabled ALL the plugins, and reverted to the default theme, then no. there should not be nothing else conflicting and this should work,. all you can do is to reinstall wordpress (not the DB - just the FILES ) and try again with the 3 conditions above mentioned . (no plugins , default theme , and priority all at once)

Comment: hi I just found out something that might help us figure this out. When I display the short-code two times in two text_widgets, only the first one shows.

Comment: It would be useful for other people also to know how , and what exactly was the problem..

Comment: to tell you the truth i didn't close wp_enqueue_script